# Nokia E71 - USB mode and Linux and Python

Tags: linux, usb, python, media

I just got a Nokia E71, and a friend installed Python on it - which ought to be uber-cool.

But here's what's driving me mad at present :

I plug in the USB cable to connect to my Linux laptop.

It says "Select USB mode:" from which I can choose one of "Mass Storage" and "Media Transfer".

If I choose Mass Storage, the phone gets mounted on my computer as a drive called "disk". This lets me copy Python programs over.

However, now Python on the phone can't see the program (if I try "option -> run script" inside python. It can't see anything on this drive.)

OTOH, if I mount as Media Transfer, my computer can no longer se the drive, but now python can find the script on the "e:\" drive.

There seems to be no way to have both the drive mounted from linux AND visible to Python at the same time. Anyone understand this? Or have experience with developing with Python for Nokia / Symbian?

Update :

Why the hell was this closed as not sys-admin related? It's about mounting drives and seeing them on a computer! What's not sys-admin about that?

Comment: This is not Sys-Admi Related. That's y it got closed and migrate to super user

Answer (score 1):

When the phone is connected in USB Mass Storage mode, the applications on the phone cannot access the contents of the memory card. You need to disconnect first before you can access the files on the SD card from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here i would like to explain about the modes

****Mass Storage Mode ****

In mass storage mode, the phone appears as a disk on the computer when connected via USB, just like a keychain USB flash drive. Files can be moved to and from the phone simply by dragging and dropping files on the computer. Many phones require that this mode be enabled using a settings menu.

**Media Transfer Mode :**

Which is uese MTP protocol for transfering music , video files from device to pc vice versa.

Thats y you are able to see the phyton programm in mass storage mode. because that time it will just show all files in mass storage . but in media transfer it will be show only media files .